# ContactEntry( ) in ContactEntry cannot be applied

Tags: java, arraylist, constructor

I am trying to make an association list for names and emails under a contact list for class. But I don't know what is wrong with my code or really, more accurately, what it is missing?

The directions are:

"One particularly common data structure is association lists. The standard example of an association list is a dictionary. A dictionary associates definitions with words. Given an word, you can use the dictionary to look up its definition. We ca think of the dictionary as being a list of pairs of the form (w,d), where w is a word and d is its definition. A general association list is a list of pairs (k,v), where k is some "key" value, and v is a value associated to that key. In general, we want to assume that no two pairs in the list have the same key. The basic operation on association lists is : Given a key, k, find the value v associated with k, if any.

Association list are very widely used in computer science. For example, a compiler has to keep track of the location in memory associated with each variable. It can do this with an association list in which each key is an variable name and the associated value is the address of that variable in memory. Another example would be a contact list, if we think of it as associating an email address to each name on the list. The items in the list could be objects belonging to the class:

The data for a contacts list consists of a ArrayList of ContactEntry and an integer variable to keep track of how many entries are actually stored in the list. A contact list could be an object belonging too the class:

Note that the search method, getEmail, returns the value that it finds associated with the key, name. This is often done with association lists.

The program could use a lot of improvement.

Modify ContactEntry adding setters, getters, a default constructor, and a constructor whose input is a name and email.

Modify ContactList to use the above and add its own setters, getters and a default constructor.

A contact list is pretty useless unless the data in the list can be saved permanently -- that is, in a file. Add the following methods to the contact list program, such that it keeps its list of names and email addresses in a file.

Thank you to anyone who helps me in advance. I am not the brightest star.

Some sample and starting code was provided but I am sure the issue is past that. I have tried googling the question but everything is different to the point that I am not sure exactly what my problem is.

```
public class ContactEntry {
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

private String name;

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

private String email;
}

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.*;
public class ContactList {
private ArrayList<ContactEntry> list=new ArrayList<ContactEntry>();
private int entries=0;

public void addEntry(String name,String email){
    ContactEntry entry=new ContactEntry(name, email);
    list.add(entry);
    entries++;
}
public String getEmail(String name){
    for(ContactEntry entry:list){
        if(entry.getName().equals(name)){
            return entry.getEmail();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
public static ContactList LoadContacts(String filepath){
    File file=new File(filepath);
    try (Scanner scan=new Scanner( file )){
        ContactList contactList=new ContactList()
        while(scan.hasNext()){
            String line=scan.nextLine();
            int pos=line.indexOf(':');
            String name=line.substring(0,pos);
            String email=line.substring(pos+1);
            contactList.addEntry(name,email);
        }
        return contactList;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
public void storeContacts(String filepath){
    File file=new File(filepath);
    try(PrintWriter pwt=new PrintWriter(file)){
        for(ContactEntry entry:list){
            pwt.println(entry.getName()+":"+entry.getEmail());
        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ContactList contactList=new ContactList();
    ContactList.addEntry( name:"tim",email:"tim@gmail.com");
    ContactList.storeContacts(filepath:"contacts.txt");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need what is called a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html). Oracle says

> A class contains constructors that are invoked to create objects from the class blueprint.

The constructor allows you to make an object which holds data. By default, all classes have a "default constructor" which is just empty and looks like

```
public ContactEntry() {

}
```

You need a constructor which takes in `String name` and `String email`. This would look something like

```
public ContactEntry(String name, String email) {
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the response, however my second piece of code still has errors such as "can't resolve symbol 'File'" which I think is solved by importing "java.io.File" even though I am unsure what exactly that does. beyond that my main method does not seem to work  giving errors "cannot resolve symbol 'name" and "non-static method 'addEntry' cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: You can see what importing does [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html). Your main method is incorrect. When you call `ContactList.XXX` it tries to call what is known as a "static" method. I won't explain to you what it is as I don't want to confuse you, but you need to instead call `contactList.XXX` and use the variable you made. When calling a method, you do not need stuff like `name:` in front. You need to remove this. For example, instead of  `name:"tim"` it should be just `"tim"`. If you have any more questions, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined a [constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) for your class, which means it has the implicit no-argument constructor only (`new ContactEntry()`). If you want a constructor that takes name and email, you must define it.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a parameterized constructor in ContactEntry class.

```
public ContactEntry(String name,String email){
      this.name=name;
      this.email=email;
}
```